# Mustache nested templates

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am wondering if this is possible. In this example the HTML file would be:

> {{i18n.sample_message}}

in my render function I have this:

```
var json = {
 i18n:i18n,
 sampleDate:'10/10/10'
}
$('div').html(Mustache.to_html(template,json);
```

The `i18n` file is an object and would have a key:

sample_message: `some long message

date is: {{json.sampleDate}}`

right now I get `{{json.sampleDate}}` on the screen. I have tried ending the string at the semicolon and using + to concatenate the value but that did not work either.

For the time being I am not putting `{{json.sampleDate}}` in the `i18n` map I changed my html to

```
{{i18n.sample_message}}{{json.sampleDate}}
```

In reality I have some long paragraphs that I need to inject some dynamic values into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working in an ugly way. Please comment/edit if there is something cleaner/better.

I had to call Mustache.to_html twice.

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(template,json);
return Mustache.to_html(html,json);
```

By calling to_html again, Mustache found {{json.sampleDate}} and replaced it with the value in my json.

Comment: After some thought I moved away from the i18n having handlebars in it and arranged my HTML differently. Stylistically I think it is cleaner.